# Blazor: How to create reusable render fragment?

Tags: blazor

I have a following markup that I use often:

```
<SfDropDownList DataSource="@Model.Customers" TItem="Customer" TValue="Customer">
    <DropDownListTemplates TItem="Customer">
        <ItemTemplate Context="customer">
            <span>@customer.Name</span><span class="float-right">@customer.Site</span>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </DropDownListTemplates>
</SfDropDownList>
```

**How do I reuse DropDownListTemplates with the same parameters in multiple components?**

I was thinking, that I create I create a custom class inherited from DropDownListTemplates:

```
@inherits DropDownListTemplates<Customer>
@code { 
    override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        // this.ItemTemplate = ??
        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
    }
}
```

but how do I set ItemTemplate which is a RenderFragment parameter in the base class?

I want to avoid wrapping SfDropDownList to a custom component

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the default value for a RenderFragment parameter as below.

```razor
@ChildContent

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent {get; set;} = @<p>Some text here</p>;
}
```

Source: [blazor-university.com](https://blazor-university.com/templating-components-with-renderfragements/passing-placeholders-to-renderfragments/)

---

Edit to add: You can also define a reusable `RenderFragment` in code (.NET Core 3.1 - 5.0).

```razor
public static RenderFragment SayHello = __builder =>
{
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
};
```

A `RenderFragment` delegate can also take parameters.

```razor
<div class="chat">
    @foreach (var message in messages)
    {
        @DisplayChatMessage(message)
    }
</div>

@code {
    RenderFragment<ChatMessage> DisplayChatMessage = message => __builder =>
    {
        <div class="chat-message">
            <span class="author">@message.Author</span>
            <span class="text">@message.Text</span>
        </div>
    };
}
```

Source: [ASP.NET Core Blazor Web Assembly Performance Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-3.1#define-reusable-renderfragments-in-code)

---

Starting .NET 6.0 you define a reusable `RenderFragment` as

```razor
private RenderFragment RenderWelcomeInfo = @<p>Welcome to your new app!</p>;
```

and with parameters as

```razor
<div class="chat">
    @foreach (var message in messages)
    {
        @ChatMessageDisplay(message)
    }
</div>

@code {
    private RenderFragment<ChatMessage> ChatMessageDisplay = message =>
        @<div class="chat-message">
            <span class="author">@message.Author</span>
            <span class="text">@message.Text</span>
        </div>;
}
```

Source: [ASP.NET Core Blazor Web Assembly Performance Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/performance?view=aspnetcore-6.0#define-reusable-renderfragments-in-code)

Comment: This is incorrect. The new correct syntax is:

`message => @<dIv>etc</div>;`

Comment: @Sebazzz Updated answer for .NET 6 and newer. Thanks for pointing out that it was outdated.