# How to render html renderfragment code in blazor

Tags: blazor

I want to render the following HTML control dynamically into the .razor file

```
<input type="text" value="hola" />
```

I did the following :

```
<div>
    @att 
</div>

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? att { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
               att = @"<input type=""text"" value=""hola"" />";
        }
```

but I get an error converting string to RenderFragment type. How do I assign this?
If I convert att - it to string the value is not HTML rendered, it displays the value as a code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blazor: How to create reusable render fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64556105/blazor-how-to-create-reusable-render-fragment)

Comment: no, it doesnot.

Comment: Does the component already exists. I am looking for a way to show blazor code and render it. Did you finish the component? Can I see the code or get it via library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are trying to set a delegate to a string.  `RenderFragment` is not a string of html, it declared like this in the DotNetCore code:

```cs
public delegate void RenderFragment(RenderTreeBuilder builder);
```

Here's a version of your code that will compile and work, though why you want to do it that way?

```cs
<div>
    @att
</div>

@code {
    public RenderFragment? att { get; set; }

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        att = (__builder) =>
        {
            <input type="text" value="hola" />
        };
        
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

You have declared `att` as a parameter so you should not be setting it in your code.  Parameters should be treated as immutable outside the `SetParametersAsync` context.

This will work and I don't think breaks the rule:

```cs
    public RenderFragment? att { get; set; } = (__builder) =>
        {
            <input type="text" value="hola" />
        };
```

Comment: Thank you. Follow-up question -- how this code setting `att` should look like when puting in .cs file, and not in .razor? `__builder.AddMarkupContent(0,...` looks like working though.

Comment: See this article - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5277618/A-Dive-into-Blazor-Components - or  - https://chrissainty.com/building-components-via-rendertreebuilder/ - and various others search "Blazor RenderTreeBuilder".

Answer (score 4):

The basic answer would be

```
RenderFragment attFallback => @<input type="text" value="hola" /> ;

RenderFragment att => attParam ?? attFallback;
```

and then use `@att` in your markup.

but it depends on what you actually want to do with that `<input>`. When you @bind to something it gets more complicated.